# UIWebView sometimes displays HTML code instead of rendering

Tags: html, uiwebview

One of my testers for an app that loads URL's in a UIWebView, reported that sometimes, instead of seeing a normal, rendered webpage, he saw the HTML code for it (like he would be viewing the source of the webpage).

Does anyone know in what case this would happen?

One of the possibilities that my team was throwing around was that there could be some invalid HTML/JS that couldn't be parsed correctly.